# How do I access item values when binding a column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm new to asp.net mvc as well as kendoui so this question may seem trivial (for both kendo and mvc).  But any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

I'm building a grid using the kendo ui mvc helper.  And there are many situations where I want to access item data.  I've figured out how to access it when created a template for a given cell as seen below.

As you can, I've created a function to create a data attribute, and I would like to read that attribute from the database rather than hardcoding it.  Here is the code that I currently have.

```
@functions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, object> BuildGroupNameAttributes(string value)
    {
        var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-groupname", value } };
        return attributes;
    }
}
<div id="dotComDiv">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
          .Name("DotComGrid")

          .Columns(columns =>
          {                  
              columns.Bound(p => p.GrossDemand.ThisYear).Title("TY").HeaderHtmlAttributes(BuildGroupNameAttributes("Gross Demand"));
              columns.Bound(p => p.GrossDemand.ThisYear).Title("TY").HeaderHtmlAttributes(BuildGroupNameAttributes("Gross Demand")).Template(@<text>@string.Format("{0:0,0}", @item.GrossDemand.ThisYear)</text>);

          }).Scrollable(src => src.Height(500))


          )
</div>
```

The line that I can't seem to work out is

```
columns.Bound(p => p.GrossDemand.ThisYear).Title("TY").HeaderHtmlAttributes(BuildGroupNameAttributes("Gross Demand"));
```

Instead of hardcoding "Gross Demand" I want to read that from the bound item.  So like,

```
columns.Bound(p => p.GrossDemand.ThisYear).Title("TY").HeaderHtmlAttributes(BuildGroupNameAttributes(@item.GroupName));
```

However, I can't access the item object like this.  But if you look at the template above, I'm able to access `@item` if it's wrapped in `@<text>`

Why is that, and how can I pass the item value to the function?

Thanks!

```
@model IEnumerable<KendoTest.Models.DotComGridModel>


public class GridColumnGroup
{
    public string ColumnGroupName { get; set; }
    public double ThisYear { get; set; }
    public double LastYear { get; set; }
    public double Planned { get; set; }
}

public class DotComGridModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GridColumnGroup GrossDemand { get; set; }
    public GridColumnGroup Shipped { get; set; }
    public GridColumnGroup ReturnRate { get; set; }
    public GridColumnGroup DemandGM { get; set; }
    public GridColumnGroup Traffic { get; set; }
    public GridColumnGroup DemanConversion { get; set; }
    public GridColumnGroup DemandAOV { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I assume that your partial view is strongly typed. Could you please post the `@model` declaration?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the model.

Comment: Also, I'm fully aware that the model doesn't have a `GroupName` property.  I just put that in as pseudocode for readability purposes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find a viable solution for your problem. I deleted my (partial) answer. I do wonder though, why don't you use the client side API for getting the values of the grid?

Comment: What do you mean?  I'm not locked into this method.

Comment: You can use the [`Selectable()`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBuilder#methods-Selectable(System.Action<Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridSelectionSettingsBuilder>)) method to set how the grid can be selected: per row or cell, one object or more. Then you can use the API [`select`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-select) function from JQuery to get the currently selected cell/row and get your data. There's no need to "hide" your data in custom attributes.

Comment: Oh, no this is something completely different.  I'm building a second header row in jquery, and the group name is what's used to determine how many new header cells there are and how many columns they should span.  This is the end result: http://i.imgur.com/Whvvn4m.png

Comment: OK, now I get it. In this case, I can't really recommend anything other than setting those values in a hidden field in the `Template()` method, as there you can access the model. This will, of course, add those values for every row. An alternative would be to get that data using an Ajax request.